# How to hide a qscrollbar context menu in QT

Tags: qt, scroll, scrollbar, qscrollarea

How can i hide the scrollbar context menu that appears when you right-click on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a QScrollArea, first you access both scrolls, and then you change the context menu policy to NoContextPolicy by using:

```
scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
```